# Amazon SNS: JSON toasts to Windows Phones

Tags: json, push-notification, mpns, amazon-sns

When I use the Amazon SNS console to send toast messages to a Windows Phone 8 device (i.e. with the MPNS system), I can only send messages in text format. Selecting "*Use platform specific JSON message dictionaries*" and sending a JSON toast never seems to get to the device. The default message that you see when you select the platform specific format is a tile notification message, and that *does* work.

For exmple, the following message neither gives an error nor is displayed in the device:

```json
{
"MPNS": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\"><wp:Toast><wp:Text1>Amazon</wp:Text1><wp:Text2>hooray</wp:Text2><wp:Param>this_is/my?extra=parameter</wp:Param></wp:Toast></wp:Notification>"
}
```

This has been tested with a couple of devices: Lumia 620 with Windows Phone 8.0 and Lumia 1020 with 8.1 beta. I have also tried sending messages from a Java backend, but it just shows up as a raw JSON text toast (`{ "MPNS": ...`) again. What could possibly be wrong? The JSON is valid, the XML is well-formed... I'm at loss.

Comment: I see that you receive some kind of answer to your question over here - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=159394&tstart=0

Comment: Only in the sense that someone else just said that they have the same problem as well.

Comment: i can see this is an old question . are you able to solve this issue

Comment: Nope, had to settle for plain text messages. :(

Comment: @NitinJain, could you check vzsg's answer and see if that solves the problem? This was a work-related project for me and unfortunately I don't work with this anymore.

Comment: @ZeroOne yeah it seems a fix with the help of message attribute section

Comment: Excellent, thanks for confirming it @NitinJain! I've accepted and upvoted vzsg's answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue recently, and found a solution. The SNS documentation for MPNS does not emphasise an important step, but it can be found in the [sample code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/samples/snsmobilepush.zip) and eventually in the [message attributes section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html) of the docs.

---

You **must** set two MPNS-specific MessageAttributes on the PublishRequest. Omitting them will cause the delivery to fail with no clues left to investigate: i.e. even if you enable delivery status logs with CloudWatch, `providerResponse` will be missing.

For reference, the attributes are the following:

1. Attribute name: `AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.Type`
   Possible values: `token` (for *tile* notifications), `toast` or `raw`
2. Attribute name: `AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.NotificationClass`
   Possible values: `realtime`*, `priority`, `regular`
   (realtime worked for me)

---

That said, it seems that [it is not possible](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=159394&tstart=0#jive-message-629830) to send custom content to MPNS using the SNS console. But using the API works, so here is an excerpt from the Java sample for using the Java SDK:

```
AmazonSNS snsClient = ... /* initialise the client */;

Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> notificationAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
notificationAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.Type",
        new MessageAttributeValue()
            .withDataType("String")
            .withStringValue("token")); // or "toast" or "raw", depending on the payload
notificationAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.MOBILE.MPNS.NotificationClass",
        new MessageAttributeValue()
            .withDataType("String")
            .withStringValue("realtime"));

PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest();
request.setMessageAttributes(notificationAttributes);
request.setMessageStructure("json");

request.setTargetArn(... /* topic or endpoint ARN */);
request.setMessage(... /* JSON payload */)

snsClient.publish(request);
```